# Reflection exclude all attributes from base class and specific attribute from all other derived classes

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection

I have the following base, middle and derived classes below::

```
public class Base
{
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public int ValueBase { get; set; }

    [IgnoreForAllAttribute("Param1", "Param2")]
    public int IgnoreBase { get; set; }
}

public class Middle : Base
{
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public int ValueMiddle { get; set; }

    [IgnoreForAllAttribute("Param1", "Param2")]
    public int IgnoreMiddle { get; set; }
}

public class MostDerived : Middle
{
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public int ValueMostDerived { get; set; }

    [IgnoreForAllAttribute("Param1", "Param2")]
    public int IgnoreMostDerived { get; set; }
}
```

I need a function that given a type, I need to return DataMemberAttribute attributes for all classes in the hierarchy except for the base.

In addition, all IgnoreForAllAttribute attributes should be ignored for all classes in the graph.

```
var derivedObject = new MostDerived();
var attributes = MyShinyAttributeFunction(derivedObject.GetType());
// returns [] { ValueMostDerived, ValueMiddle }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a LINQ sample that assumes DateMemberAttribute and IgnoreForAllAttribute are mutually exclusive

```
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> MyProperties(object o)
{
   o.GetType().GetProperties()
    .Where(p => !(p.DeclaringType is Base))
    .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(false).Any(a => a is DataMemberAttribute)
}
```

And a sample assuming the attributes are NOT mutually exclusive

```
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> MyProperties(object o)
{
   o.GetType().GetProperties()
    .Where(p => !(p.DeclaringType is Base))
    .Where(p => 
       { 
          var attributes = p.GetCustomAttributes(false);
          return attributes.Any(a => a is DataMemberAttribute)
             && !attributes.Any(a => a is IgnoreForAllAttribute);
       }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `p.DeclaringType == typeof(Base)`? As `DeclaringType` returns a `Type`?

Answer (score 3):

```
var properties = new List<PropertyInfo>();

GetProps(typeof(MostDerived), properties);
```

GetProps is a recursive function that gets the properties for the declaring type and then calls itself for the next type in the hierarchy. It stops when it gets to 'Base'

```
private static void GetProps(Type T, List<PropertyInfo> Properties)
{
  if (T != typeof(Base))
  {
    var pis = T.GetProperties();

    foreach (var pi in pis)
    {
      if (pi.DeclaringType == T &&
        pi.GetCustomAttribute<DataMemberAttribute>() != null &&
        pi.GetCustomAttribute<IgnoreForAllAttribute>() == null)
      {
        Properties.Add(pi);
      }
    }

    GetProps(T.BaseType, Properties);

  }
}
```

The properties list will contain properties which have the DataMemberAttribute and don't have the IgnoreForAllAttribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following function to get desired results:
In propertyNames, you will get the properties you need.

Usage:

```
List<string> propertyNames = new List<string>();
List<string> basePropertyNames = new List<string>();
MyShinyAttributeFunction(derivedObject.GetType(), ref propertyNames, ref basePropertyNames);
```

Function:

```
void MyShinyAttributeFunction(Type type, ref List<string> propertyNames, ref List<string> basePropertyNames)
{
    if (type == null)
        return;

    MyShinyAttributeFunction(type.BaseType, ref propertyNames, ref basePropertyNames);

    foreach (var property in type.GetProperties())
    {
        foreach (object customAttr in property.GetCustomAttributes(false))
        {
            if (customAttr is DataMemberAttribute)
            {
                if (type.BaseType.Name.Equals("Object"))
                {
                    DataMemberAttribute attribute = (DataMemberAttribute)customAttr;
                    if (!basePropertyNames.Contains(property.Name))
                        basePropertyNames.Add(property.Name);
                }
                else
                {
                    DataMemberAttribute attribute = (DataMemberAttribute)customAttr;
                    if (!propertyNames.Contains(property.Name) && !basePropertyNames.Contains(property.Name))
                        propertyNames.Add(property.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must make use of the following:

- [Type::GetProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx) method, to retrieve all properties.
- [MemberInfo::GetCustomAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwc6ew1d.aspx) to retrieve the attributes for each property.
- [Type::BaseType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.basetype.aspx) property to retrieve base type for a type.

A recursive function that stops when BaseType does not exist should do the trick.