# How to determine if the property belongs to Base class or sub class dynamically in generic type using reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance, reflection

I have following two classes (models), one is base class and other is sub class:

```
public class BaseClass
{    
     public string BaseProperty{get;set;}    
}

public class ChildClass: BaseClass    
{    
     public string ChildProperty{get;set;}    
}
```

In application I am calling `ChildClass` dynamically using generics

```
List<string> propertyNames=new List<string>();
foreach (PropertyInfo info in typeof(T).GetProperties())
{
      propertyNames.Add(info.Name);
}
```

Here, in `propertyNames` list, I am getting property for `BaseClass` as well. I want only those properties which are in child class. Is this possible?

What I tried?

1. Tried excluding it as mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051834/exclude-property-from-gettype-getproperties)
2. Tried determining whether the class is sub class or base class as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742276/how-do-i-check-if-a-type-is-a-subtype-or-the-type-of-an-object) but that does not help either.

Comment: Nice q. I think you mean using Reflection though and not Generics?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667219/reflection-exclude-all-attributes-from-base-class-and-specific-attribute-from-al

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try this

```
foreach (PropertyInfo info in typeof(T).GetProperties()
        .Where(x=>x.DeclaringType == typeof(T))) // filtering by declaring type
{
    propertyNames.Add(info.Name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked like a charm :) You save my lot of time.

Answer (score 4):

> ...I want only those properties which are in child class. Is this possible?

You need to use the [GetProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x(v=vs.110).aspx) overload that takes a [BindingFlags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags(v=vs.110).aspx) argument and include the `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` flag.

```
PropertyInfo[] infos = typeof(ChildClass).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```

> DeclaredOnly:  Specifies that only members declared at the level of the supplied type's hierarchy should be considered. Inherited members are not considered.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not return me any properties. Am i missing something. You check this [demo](http://rextester.com/MNAHMY33063) I made using your code.

Comment: @KaranDesai, you need to include the three BindingFlags I showed above.  When you call `GetProperties` without specifying any BindingFlags, it uses `BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance`.  So you may want to include `BindingFlags.Static` to the list; it just depends what you want to retrieve and is the reason that I provided the link to the BindingFlags documentation.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. DeclaredOnly's description confused me. This worked too when I added all three flags. +1

Answer (score 2):

Using a simple loop to get the base class property names

```
var type = typeof(T);

var nameOfBaseType = "Object";

while (type.BaseType.Name != nameOfBaseType)
{
    type = type.BaseType;
}

propertyNames.AddRange(type.GetProperties().Select(x => x.Name))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want base class property names. I want only child class property names. Also, everything happens dynamically so I might not hardcode and assign `nameofBaseType` variable.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to get from the base class the derived class name and properties but nothing about the base class...

Based on the top answer I used the following... Hopefully it helps someone else!

```
public abstract class StorageObject
{
    protected readonly string TableName;
    protected readonly string[] ColumnNames;

    protected StorageObject()
    {
        TableName = GetType().Name;

        ColumnNames = GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => x.DeclaringType == GetType())
            .Select(x => x.Name)
            .ToArray();
    }
}

public class Symbol : StorageObject
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public bool MarginEnabled { get; private set; }
    public bool SpotEnabled { get; private set; }
    public Symbol(ICommonSymbol symbol)
    {
        Name = symbol.CommonName;
        
        if (symbol is BitfinexSymbolDetails bsd)
        {
            MarginEnabled = bsd.Margin;
        }

        if (symbol is BinanceSymbol bs)
        {
            SpotEnabled = bs.IsSpotTradingAllowed;
            MarginEnabled = bs.IsMarginTradingAllowed;
        }
        
    }
}
```